# How can we get the READY TO SUBMIT status of gerrit review via command line?

Tags: ssh, git-merge, gerrit, review, git-merge-conflict

I want to get the list of all the reviews which are in READY TO SUBMIT state via command line (may be use some script to automate) and merge all those reviews.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the [gerrity-query command](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html)? The [list of search operators](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [gerrit query](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html) SSH command like the following example:

```
ssh -p 29418 USER@GERRIT-SERVER gerrit query is:submittable
```

See more info about search queries on Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html).